# Relevance of polyfills and shims

Tags: javascript, html, css, polyfills

So it's 2016. ECMAScript 2015 has been pretty much standardised. HTML5 and CSS3, although with a few minor quirks, is considerably usable.

**However,** tutorials nowadays still include polyfills and shims (good example being the [Angular 2 quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)). It seems illogical to me.

My inference of standardisation comes from [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com) and the [Kangax ES6 compatibility tables](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

I would have agreed that Internet Explorer would be a main reason (darn you, MS) but I've checked the [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com) usage-oriented tables and IE11 has only (as of 23 November, 2016) 3% usage in the world.

Then again, I've also checked ES6 support by browsers and browsers have 90% or above support (with Chrome leading with 97% and Safari 10 supposedly having 100% support).

So back to my question,

**Why are polyfills still used if browsers have already caught up?**

Cheers!

Comment: downvoter please explain

Comment: I'm not sure what figures on caniuse you're talking about, but IE has a **lot** more than a 3% worldwide market share. As of October 2016, it's more like [**22%**](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0). That's still pretty relevant. Of course, 11.92% of that is IE11 which has pretty good ES5 support (but not good ES2015 support). *(this is not a reply to your comment above, just an observation on the question)*

Comment: It of course depends on the requirements of the individual project, but even a small percentage of the >3 billion people on the internet is not insignificant.

Comment: I think your premise is off a bit - browsers have caught up (mostly), but not all users are using the latest browsers, therefore polyfills are not illogical but necessary.

Comment: 1/ That's a lot of users 2/ 3% of ES6 features not working _at least_ is huge if you expect your code to work, as well as (as a comparison) for a server an uptime of 99.9% is poor when you need 99.99999%. YMMV and that isn't the sort of question that is wanted on SO: there aren't definitve answers and it's way too opened

Comment: @FelipeAls understood... will be careful next time

Comment: Also HTML5 and CSS3 aren't "usable" for everybody. Yeah float works. My (huge) client has ditched Android 4.3 and less so I can use mighty flexbox (with wrap) but is Grid Layout supported anywhere except IE/Edge? Nope (in 2016). HTML5 and CSS Level 3 are kind of huge with many many APIs and Modules. Usable for some, slooow adoption for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the one answer that can answer most questions surrounding older techniques in use by newer standard is because of legacy code and backwards compatibility. At the end of the day there will always be older code that needs to be ran by your browser, if we left support for polyfills off in ES6 then we would shatter a lot of websites. Beyond that, a lot of people decide (for whatever reason) not to update, things like polyfill can be used as legacy fall backs in the event a browser doesn't support a newer mechanic and instead requires something like polyfill to take it's place.

Answer (score 2):

even a low percentage is still a considerable amount of people.

a client trying to reach people with a website/app doesn't care about the technical beauty of es2015, he cares about not looking like an ass when someone uses ie 6 on windows xp and can't access their services.

is it your personal website/experiment? feel free to ignore the shims.
is it a job someone is paying for? ignore what looks cool and do what's right for them, shims included.